# how to set variable values, skipping some variables and keeping this with the default value

Tags: css, variables

I found several other ways to do this .. but want to know if is possible to do as my example below

these mix:

```
.mix( @marg: 1px, @pad:2px, @bg: red ){
    margin:@marg;
    padding:@pad;
    background:@bg;
}
```

example 1:

```
span{
    .mix(5px);
}
```

Will result in:

```
span {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

But If I like to set the margin and background... and keep padding like default how jump over padding? or if I need set just padding and background how jump over margin and mantain it with default value??

Summarizing..

Is possible make some like these:

```
span{
    .mix(15px, default, blue);
}
```

Result:

```
span {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
span{
    .mix(@marg:15px, @bg:blue);
}
```

Comment: so simple... thz for that